# Maintain aspect ratio while keeping 100% width of fluid container

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html5-video

For the following items, I want to style as follows:

1. `parentContainer` - width 100vw and height 100vh; all items must fit within the container (ie no scrollbars)
2. `searchBar` - at top; will take width 100vw and height is based on content
3. `bottomContainer` - takes remaining space not consumed by `searchBar`
4. `videoContainer` - contains a video element and a title; both items must fit within the full height of the `bottomContainer` BUT the video element must maintain `16:9` aspect ratio; all remaining width should be filled by `sidebarContainer`
5. `video` - no source will be provided initially but must maintain aspect ratio of `16:9`;
6. `sidebarContainer` - some random content that would have a `minWidth: 150px` (on smaller screens it will disappear); will take remaining width not used by videoContainer;

I was able to meet most of the requirements but the `videoContainer` / `video`. If I fix the ratio issue, the `video` element is too small. If I fix the `video` element size, the aspect ratio isn't maintained or the `videoContainer` doesn't fit within the viewport (ie usually it extends beyond the height on extremely wide screens).

Sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/video-css-structure-dfc2q?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a starting structure. The video container is full responsive 16:9 with and without the `<video>` tag. Let me know if it's not what you expected.

```
<div class="parentContainer">
  <header class="searchBar">
    <br>search<br><br>
  </header>
  <div class="rowContainer">
    <main class="videoContainer">
      <div class="video">
        video 16:9
        <!-- <video width="480" height="270" controls>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video> -->
      </div>
      <div class="video-title">
        Title of the video
      </div>
    </main>
    <aside class="sidebarContainer">
      <br>Sidebar<br><br>
    </aside>
  </div>
  <footer class="bottomContainer">
    <br>bottom<br><br>
  </footer>
</div>
```

with css code width & height 100% (or 100vw & 100vh)

```
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
}
header, main, aside, footer {
  display: block;
}
.parentContainer {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rowContainer {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebarContainer {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  width: 25%;
}
.videoContainer {
  flex: 0 0 75%;
  width: 75%;
}
.video {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* 9:16 */
}
.video video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
.parentContainer {background-color: lightgreen;}
.searchBar {background-color: yellow;}
.videoContainer {background-color: silver;}
.video-title {background-color: lightgrey;}
.sidebarContainer {background-color: pink;}
```

Comment: This is awesome. I had resorted to JavaScript to adjust my `divs`. One more question. I removed the `sidebarContainer` since it was complicating the situation. How would I readjust your scripting to fit the max-width without exceeding the height? It doesn't seem to be as easy as removing the div or adjusting the `flex 0 0 75%` . - https://codesandbox.io/s/video-css-structure-2-9ete6?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Html: remove the `aside` section. Css: set the `videoContainer` to 100% + remove temporary the `overflow: hidden;` line. Now you'll see that the `videoContainer` will grow in width **and** height. The height of the videoContainer pushes the bottomContainer outside the browser view.  There are so many different displays (monitors, laptops, tablets, etc.) that it is diffucult to show the layout correct on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If the sidebar is only a problem on smartphone then change in the css the parentContainer, rowContainer, sidebarContainer, and videoContainer to the css below.

On small screens the left and right column will stack, meaning that on small screens the video is on top of the sidebar.

```
/* overflow temporary commented for testing */
.parentContainer {
  height: 100%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
/* wrap columns if total width > 100% */
.rowContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/* small screens */
.sidebarContainer,
.videoContainer {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
/* medium and large screens */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .sidebarContainer {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    width: 25%;
  }
  .videoContainer {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```